# How to get block method in controller?

Tags: controllers, blocks

My block file path is

```
app\code\local\Company\Modulename\Block\Product\View\View.php
```

In this file method name is getId()

Now how to call call this method in controller?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hi you can call this block by using below code at controller.

```
$block=$this->getLayout()->createBlock('blockPrefix/product_view_view');

$Id=$block->getId();
```

Block Prefix is define at **app\code\local\Company\Modulename\Block\Product\View\View.php under  tag**

```
   <blocks>
        <blockPrefix><!-- guess that modulePrefix is your module block prefix -->
        <class>Company_Modulenam_Block</class>
        </blockPrefix>
    </blocks>
```

See at how to call a block check [at  here](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/)

Answer (score 12):

If your block is already attached to the action of the controller you can call it like

```
$this->getBlock('block.name.here')->getId()
```

If the block has nothing to do with your current action you can call it like :

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('[module]/product_view')->getId()
```

Comment: I'm not sure the second example works in, at least not in 1.9.2.1. The method's doc block says it's deprecated and to use `self::helper()` which is odd in itself, because blocks and helpers are different things!